# Clusters centers for Distance-based clustering

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, cluster-analysis

I implement [Distance-based clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#distancebasedclustering) based on [android-maps-utils implementation](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.java), but I want to use more friendly clusters centers (not the first marker in the cluster like proposed). Any ideas without big performance losing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Density based clusters can be of arbitrary shape.

For non-convex clusters, **the center can be outside of the cluster**.

For such clustering, clusters are not well represented with any single sample. Instead, you would better characterize them by their *cover* or *shape*.